# How to return value from PL/SQL query (with dbms_output) to JMeters View Results Tree?

Tags: sql, oracle, jdbc, plsql, jmeter

I have PL/SQL query:

```
declare
  l_result integer;
begin
  l_res := [Calling another procedure]
  dbms_output.put_line('res = '||l_res);
end;
```

When i am trying to execute it in JMeter as JDBC Request (query type: Callable Statement) it returns "Response code is 200 & OK" but nothing in response data because i am outputting to dbms. So how can i return the l_res as "Response Data" so i can check it in "View Results Test"?

return l_res is not working because "PLS-00372: In a procedure, RETURN statement cannot contain an expression".

The question for me is: How to return variable value as Response Data from anonymous PLSQL block.

[JMeter JDBC Request interface (image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k1uqL.png)

Comment: Why do you need a PL/SQL block - can't you call the function (not procedure, since you're already assigning its return value to a variable) directly, or in a query?

Comment: I have a little bit more complex logic so i cant just call function in this block. I am new with plsql/jmeter so i dont have many ways to think about it. That is why, just returning l_res value seems to me the most easy way.

Comment: Then can JMeter bind an output variable for the call to your anonymous block; so rather than having a local variable declared, have `:l_res := <your function>`? The colon before the name indicates it's a bind variable. Or maybe `? := <your_function>`? (I don't use JMeter, no idea exactly how that would be bound...)

Comment: I added :l_res in declare block, and "Result variable name: OUT". 
I think wrapping and storing this block with "CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION" not gonna help me, because i still be querying anonymous block to execute this function.

The question for me is: how to return variable as Response Data from anynoumous PLSQL block.